# Error when joining file to path in python

Tags: python, os.path

Below is the code I am writing to look at mutilpe CSV files, pull the data in mutiple file's data into array then put into a pandas dataframe so I can do evaluation and prepare it for classification and transformation.  I keep getting an error as show below...  what am I missing... using Juypter Notebook to write code on Python3 kernal

```
**Error:**
  File "<ipython-input-35-d756f7ff80cd>", line 13
    if isinstance(file_path)
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Code**

```
import os
import csv
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import stat


def file_path(destinationFile):
    os.chmod(destinationFile, stat.S_IWRITE)
def join(file_path, read_files):
    path = os.fspath(file_path)
    if isinstance(file_path)
        sep = b'\\

    file_path = open(r"C:\Users\Nicole-local\Downloads\data_engineer_test (4)\data_engineer_test")
read_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(file_path,"*.csv"))


np_array_values = []
for files in read_files:
        sms_data = pd.read_csv(files, header=0)
        np_array_value.append(sms_data)
```

Comment: You're missing a `:` at the end of the `if` line. Also, `isinstance` takes two arguments.

Comment: `sep = b'\\ ` is missing the ending quote.